# Looking for a working example of kendo Mobile Grid in TelerikAppBuilder

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, telerik-appbuilder

I have started to do this example

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/adaptive

but I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoGrid is not a function`

I think its because the AppBuilder Template just references Kendo Core and not

kendo.all.min.js still looking into it but figured someone else might have some 
pointers

Comment: You're exactly right - the version of Kendo UI delivered with AppBuilder is a custom build that focused on the mobile-optimized components. You certainly can use the full Kendo UI distribution though and leverage the other widgets like the Grid.

Comment: Have you done that before ?

Comment: At some point, yes. The widgets are responsive, so while not perfect for a mobile app, they will function.